# Show that $ \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{li}(x)^2 (x - 1)}{x^4} dx = \frac{5 \pi^2}{36} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals, special-functions, riemann-zeta

We know

$$\int_{0}^{1}\Big(\frac{\operatorname{li}(x)}{x}\Big)^2dx= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

and

$$\int_0^1 4 \space\operatorname{li}(x)^3 \space (x-1) \space x^{-3} dx = \zeta(3) $$

see the proofs :

[prove that $\int_{0}^{1}\Big(\frac{\operatorname{li}(x)}{x}\Big)^2dx= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633058/prove-that-int-01-big-frac-operatornamelixx-big2dx-frac-pi)

[Show that $\int_0^1 4 \space\operatorname{li}(x)^3 \space (x-1) \space x^{-3} dx = \zeta(3) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2866629/show-that-int-01-4-space-operatornamelix3-space-x-1-space-x-3-dx)

But we also have this similar one :

$$  \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{li}(x)^2 (x - 1)}{x^4} dx = \frac{5 \pi^2}{36} $$

That one is much harder to explain.
Notice it is probably harder because the powers of $\operatorname{li}(x)^2$ and $x^4$ do not match and the integral is going from $1$ to $\infty$ !

How to prove this equality ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork the methods for solving the other two, contour integration , rossers theorem, ramanujan master theorem , laplace transformations , zeta representations and the usual stuff.

Comment: I wonder if it is fruitful to split the integral into two divergent integrals , do some kind of summabilty methods and then add them to get the result. But while being formal ofcourse !

Comment: Not my question, which was what have you *TRIED*?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I said what I tried. And I checked numerically with computer.
Maybe I made an error, sorry I did not keep the notes.

Comment: I tried substitutions $1/x$ and $\exp(x)$ but without success.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but when people ask what your attempts are, they want to see those attempts in the question, not in the comments. Everyone would prefer seeing "I tried $x \mapsto 1/x$ so that my integral becomes $\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}(1/x)^2 (1/x-1)}{(1/x)^4}\frac{dx}{x^2}$" or something specific like that.

Comment: @Accelerator I know, but I was not able to get anything significant. I was not able to simplify the integrand. I was not able to find a series expansion or product expansion or limit that seemed easier.
Btw li(x) , the logarithmic integral , not Li(x) the polylog !

Comment: I will think about it...

Comment: I understand, but even if you think your attempts are futile, you would still need to put those attempts into the post if you want to attract good answers.

Comment: And who knows, maybe someone would be able to use your ideas and implement that into their own answer.

Comment: Ok I have a proof.... but it is waaayy to long ...
Will post later when I have time.

Comment: Please do. I'm interested in seeing it. @mick

Comment: I found a PDF file but I can not add PDF files ??

Answer (score 6):

I'm just finishing the answer by Marco Cantarini, with $$\newcommand{\li}{\operatorname{li}}\newcommand{\dilog}{\operatorname{Li}_2}\int_1^\infty\li(x)x^{s-1}\,dx=\frac{\log(-1-s)}{s}$$ (for $\Re s<-1$) [touched in the past](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4102782) *(which calls for the Mellin transform of $\li(x)^2$ via [multiplication/convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#Parseval%27s_theorem_and_Plancherel%27s_theorem))*. It turns out that *the latter* has a closed form in terms of the [dilogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function) function *(which suggests doing integrals with $\li(x)^3$ or $\li(x)^4$ the same way)*.

As a result, for $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and $0<c<\Re a$ we have $$\int_1^\infty\frac{\li(x)^2}{x^{3+a}}\,dx=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\log s}{1+s}\frac{\log(a-s)}{1+a-s}\,ds.$$

The integral above is transformed into a [principal-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) integral along the negative real axis: $$\int_1^\infty\frac{\li(x)^2}{x^{3+a}}\,dx=\text{p.v.}\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(a+x)}{1+a+x}\frac{dx}{x-1}.$$ This is done via the [Cauchy integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) applied to the boundary of $$\{s\in\mathbb{C}:r<|s|<R\land\Re s<c\land(\Re s>0\lor|\Im s|>r)\}$$ (the part of $|s|<R$ to the left of $\Re s=c$, with a notch around the negative real axis), and taking $R\to\infty$ and $r\to 0$. The latter should be done with care, since $s=-1$ is a singularity *on the branch cut* of the integrand, but its [contributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/319959) (at the edges of the cut) cancel each other.

A straightforward *(but tedious)* way to get a closed form of the last integral (in terms of the dilogarithm) is to write $\text{p.v.}\int_0^\infty=\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}\lim\limits_{r\to 0}\left(\int_0^{1-r}+\int_{1+r}^R\right)$ and evaluate the integrals individually. After simplification using dilogarithm identities, if we put $a=s-1$, we get $$f(s):=\int_1^\infty\frac{\li(x)^2}{x^{2+s}}\,dx=\frac1{1+s}\left[\frac{\pi^2}6+\log(s)^2+2\dilog\left(\frac1s\right)\right]$$ for $\Re s\geqslant 1$. The values of $\dilog(1)$ and $\dilog(1/2)$ yield $f(1)=\pi^2/4$ and $f(2)=\pi^2/9$.

Finally, the value of the given integral is $f(1)-f(2)=5\pi^2/36$ as expected.

Comment: (+1) Very nice!

Comment: +1 to you and Marco.
There exists an elementary proof by Alexander Lemmens, who is a friend of my mentor (and my mentor came with the integral). I  wanted to add the pdf here but adding pdf is not possible ?? 
So I need to type it out completely ?

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer. We start from the [Mellin transform](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/LogIntegral/21/02/01/) $$\int_{1}^{+\infty}x^{s-1}\text{li}(x)dx=\frac{-\log\left(-s-1\right)}{s},\,\text{Re}(s)<-1.$$ Then, from [Plancherel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#Parseval%27s_theorem_and_Plancherel%27s_theorem), we get $$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{li}(x)^{2}}{x^{3}}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\left|\log\left(-it\right)\right|^{2}}{1+t^{2}}dt$$ where we are assuming that $\log(x)$ is the principal value $\text{Log}(z)$. Hence, the problem boils down to the evaluation of $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log\left(t\right)^{2}}{1+t^{2}}dt=\frac{\pi^{2}}{8},$$ which can be easily deduced from the Mellin transform $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^{s}}{1+t^{2}}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}\sec\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right),\,\text{Re}(s)>-1$$ so $$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{li}(x)^{2}}{x^{3}}dx=\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}.$$ In a similar manner, we have $$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{li}(x)^{2}}{x^{4}}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\left|\log\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)\right|^{2}}{\frac{9}{4}+t^{2}}dt$$ but this time the evaluation of the integral is less obvious. Still working on it.